# I am unable to cat multiple files in a directory

Tags: shell-script, shell

I wrote a script to get all the ddl of a table in a database and then later combine all the tables in a database into single file

Lets say I have database like `mydatabase` and table `mytable`

I dumped all the table ddl in a database to a temp directory and the ddl in temp directory looks like this `/home/rahul/temp/mydatabase.mytable.ddl` and once all the tables under a database dumped I am trying to combine all table ddl's into one single file like below

```
cat /home/rahul/temp/mydatabase*ddl >> /home/rahul/final/mydatabase.create
```

Result with the following error:

```
cat: /home/rahul/temp/mydatabase*ddl: No such file or directory
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Could you verify, with for example `ls /home/rahul/temp`, that the files that you expect to be there (the ones that should match the `mydatabas*ddl` pattern) actually exist?  Also, the error message does not match the command that you typed (`mydatabas*ddl` vs. `mydatabase*ddl`). Make sure that your question is exactly correct and corresponds to what you see.

Comment: You cat with /home/rahul/temp/mydatabas*ddl first and then /home/rahul/temp/mydatabase*ddl. the mydatabase syntax is inconsistent?

Comment: @Kusalananda sorry it's a typo error its mydatabase*ddl and the files in the directory existing

Comment: It seems to be a typo...

Comment: Does ls /home/rahul/temp/mydatabase*ddl return the same error?

Comment: You might edit your question before too many people get the idea that your "mydatabas*dll" vs "mydatabase*ddl" is a "real" typo versus a question-typo.

Comment: @Rahul please copy/paste the exact commands you are running with output and not re-typing them. The question is highly indicative of user error. It would help if you could prove to us that the files are where you say they are, such as running an `ls` in the directory, and copy/pasting something showing your current path, and the output of the `ls`.

Comment: please put the output of the command `ls -l /home/rahul/temp/`

Comment: Are you trying to do do the cat on the DB or in the machine you made the dumps? Are you mixing both?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you turned off shell globbing with `set -f`?

```
$ ls mydatabase*ddl
mydatabase1.ddl  mydatabase2.ddl  mydatabase3.ddl

$ set -f
$ ls mydatabase*ddl
ls: cannot access 'mydatabase*ddl': No such file or directory

$ set +f
$ ls mydatabase*ddl
mydatabase1.ddl  mydatabase2.ddl  mydatabase3.ddl
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jeff Schaller i already tried this option its not working

Answer (score 1):

Quick hack if `cat` isn't able to deal with `*` wildcard:

```
for file in /home/rahul/temp/mydatabase*ddl; do cat $file >> /home/rahul/final/mydatabase.create; done
```

I know i could be using shell variables for input and output files, and make a more complex shell script, but this should be good enough to handle this issue.

Comment: shouldnt `cat` be able to deal with `*`?

Comment: *if cat. typo. But you are right. it should work

Comment: @nwildner the for loop option is not working

Comment: I've create similar files at my home, and it worked. Are you sure you are not making mistakes/typos. Give more details to help our investigation

Comment: `cat` doesn't deal with `*`, the shell does.